# Selecting results with no NULL columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table with 4 columns (A, B, C and D) with 3 rows of data:

```
A   |    B    |    C    |    D
================================
12  |    13   |    14   |
15  |         |    16   |
17  |    18   |         |
```

From the table, column D does not have any data (NULL value), and columns B and C have missing (NULL) values in some rows. Is it possible to frame a query to display results from the table with only the COLUMNS that have a non-null value in them?

Comment: This kind of problem is frequently symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: change design and divide your table

Comment: Could you add an expected output for your example.

Comment: This is hypothetical, Strawberry. The desired output is:
A   |   B    |    C
======================
12  |   13   |    14
15  |        |    16
17  |   18   |

Comment: No.  A SQL query has a fixed number of columns.  If you want to have a variable number of columns, you need to use dynamic SQL via a `prepare` statement.

Comment: In other words, is there a way to place a condition which has to be met to display that particular column?

Comment: This is a poor hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your query in `WHERE` section

```
B is not null and C is not null and D is not null
```